# using MIN and NULLIF correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, min, nullif

```
$min_cost = min(NULLIF(value, 0))($cost_1, $cost_2, $cost_3, $cost_4);
```

Some costs on the database return $0.00, so that automatically becomes the $min_cost, even though there is values of more than zero on the other costs

I cant find much info on where the brackets should be on the NULLIF ? anyone help me?

Comment: `NULLIF` is a MySQL function, but you're currently trying to use it as a PHP function. You need to use it inside your MySQL query/

Comment: Is it possible for you to filter rows with $0.00 costs out using a WHERE condition?

Comment: can it be used in a WHILE loop?

Comment: while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
 $bg = ($bg=='#eeeeee' ? '#ffffff' : '#eeeeee');
 
 
 $cost_1 = $maxdistance*$row['klm_fare_1'] ;
 $cost_2 = $maxdistance*$row['klm_fare_2'] ;
 $cost_3 = $maxdistance*$row['klm_fare_3'] ;
 $cost_4 = $maxdistance*$row['klm_fare_4'] ;

    
$min_cost = min(NULLIF(value, 0))($cost_1, $cost_2, $cost_3, $cost_4);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to get rid of the 0 entries through SQL, try using array_filter.

array_filter() should get rid of the 0 entries

```
$array1 = array($cost_1, $cost_2, $cost_3, $cost_4);

$min_cost = min(array_filter($array1));
```